# Can I implement custom reduce functions in SQL

Tags: sql

There are some built-in reduce functions in SQL, for examples `count`, `sum` and `group_concat`, etc. Sometime I need to write a reduce function like them avoiding writing inefficient query with complicated joins. But I think I can't do that starting with `SELECT ...`.

Can I do that with stored procedure or function? 
I think you'd better understand what I called *reduce function* as a function that retreives multiple rows and return scalar.

Comment: They are called aggregate functions

Comment: Possibly yes depending on your RDBMS platform - include that in your question or tags.

Comment: It can be done using stored procedures, but don't expect performance.

Comment: Can you describe the problem?  Perhaps someone can give you a query which avoids the creation of a new UDF.

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? Postgres? Oracle? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product.

Comment: Specfiy for which RDBMS and specify an example.  Each RDBMS will do it things differently, and different aggregations need different code. It's not like SQL supports Lambda functions, as it's a Declarative language.

Comment: I'm using mysql and performance is not critical in my use case.